# Smart App Banner install attribution in App Store Connect App Analytics

Tags: app-store-connect

Reference: [Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

Are Smart Banner installs included in "Web Referrers" when looking at App Analytics > Sources > Web Referrers?

Definition of Web Referrers:

> Customers tapped a link form a website that brought them to your App Store product page

To me that doesn't sound like it includes Smart Banner installs.

> If you promote your app with Smart App Banners in Safari, you can add your campaign token and provider token when implementing a Smart App Banner on your website.
>   [source](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/en.lproj/static.html#itc623752a8d)

This section on Smart Banners is a separate section from app analytics / referrers. This again implies to me that smart app banners are not included in web referrers and are considered their own channel.

Does anyone know have a more concrete answer? I find the App Store Analytics incredibly inconsistent and documentation lacking.

Answer (score 3):

WWDC 2015 had a session covering this topic - https://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/303

Exact code from their slide:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreId,  affiliate-data=pt=1234&ct=My_Campaign"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just finished the below the config. The expected behavior is to see metrics for our Smart App Banner in in App Analytics > Sources > Campaigns. I suppose this is more of a workaround to your original question, but hopefully is works for you to see some data about the interactions with your banner.

1. add a campaign token (testing now)
2. add a campaign token and a provider token (have not tested)

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=ct=myCampaignToken">

<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=ct&pt=myCampaignToken&myProviderToken">
```